# How do I handle Scroll View on iPhone with run time content?

Tags: iphone

I have an array of Buttons (UIButtons), and I have to display those button on iPad.

If the number of buttons is less than 10, then all the buttons are displayed in good condition. But if the number of buttons increases to more than 15, then only 8 buttons display.

What should I do to display all the buttons using the Scroll View?

Answer (score 0):

Change the contentSize  of the scrollview upon the number of the button added on the screen.

Create a counter on the addbtn and set the content size of scrollview with 40*counter